# general array printer function in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printing, function-pointers

I've those two structs :

```
    typedef struct
    {
        char* name;
        int flightCount;
        Flight** flightArr;
        LIST dateList;
        int flightsSorted;
    
    }Airline;

typedef struct
{
    Airport*    airportsArr;
    int         airportsCount;
}AirportManager;
```

and I need to write a general printer for both arrays (one is struct array and the other is pointer array).

I know that general printer should look like that:

```
void generalArrayFunction(const void* pArr, const int size, int sizeOfElement, void(*printer)(const void*))
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    printer((char*)pArr + i * sizeOfElement);
}
```

and it's work great with the regular array which I print with the following line:

```
generalArrayFunction(manager.airportsArr,manager.airportsCount,sizeof(manager.airportsArr[0]),printAirport);
```

but with the pointer array I can't use the same logic and I dont know what should I do.the following line prints one struct but the second one messed up.

```
generalArrayFunction(*pComp->flightArr, pComp->flightCount, sizeof(pComp->flightArr[0]), printFlight);
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If i got your intention right, In this code:

```
generalArrayFunction(*pComp->flightArr, pComp->flightCount, sizeof(pComp->flightArr[0]), printFlight);
```

sizeOfElement will be the size of a pointer because it's an array of pointers, you need to make another dereference to reach the struct and get the size, that's why the first struct is printing ok and the subsequent are not.
Try this:

```
generalArrayFunction(*pComp->flightArr, pComp->flightCount, sizeof((*pComp->flightArr)[0]), printFlight)
```

Comment: cant understand the reason for your change and it's not working as well.

Comment: @יונתן אליהו I thought you need the size of the element to print correctly what ever flightArr is pointing to as flightArr is a pointer to a pointer not a pointer to some element (eg. struct) especially when the first srtuct is printed correctly (perhaps due to i * sizeOfElement when i = 0 in generalArrayFunction), but perhaps is was wrong.